# sequence with brackets

Tags: math-mode

How to get the output like this with Latex?

[image]

Comment: Try: `$\{w_t, r_t\}_{t=0}^\infty$`. This said, you should read an introductory book on latex as this is a really basic question....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the math expressions:

```
$\{\omega_t, r_t\}_{t=0}^\infty$
```